# Inline function in namespaces in C++

Tags: c++, function, linker, namespaces

I am writing a matrix library.
I put my classes inside namespace SLMath.
but because of inline functions i am getting errors.

these are my files..

Mat4.hpp

```
#ifndef INC_SLMATH_MAT4_H
#define INC_SLMATH_MAT4_H


#include<cstdint>
#include<algorithm>

namespace SLMath
{
    class Mat4
    {
        typedef std::uint8_t uint8; // You know that Its tedious to write          std::uint8_t everytime
        float matrix[16];
        inline int index(uint8 row,uint8 col) const;

    public:

        //Constructors
        Mat4();
        Mat4(const Mat4 &other);

        //Destructor
        ~Mat4();

    //operators
    void operator=(const Mat4 &other);

    //loads the identity matrix
    void reset();

    //returns the element in the given index
    inline float operator()(uint8 row,uint8 col) const;

    //returns the matrix array
    inline const float* const valuePtr();

};
}


#endif
```

and Mat4.cpp..

```
#include"Mat4.hpp"


namespace SLMath
{

//private member functions
inline int Mat4::index(uint8 row,uint8 col) const
{
    return row*4+col;
}


//Public member functions
Mat4::Mat4()
{
    reset();
}


Mat4::Mat4(const Mat4 &other)
{
    this->operator=(other);
}


Mat4::~Mat4(){}


inline float Mat4::operator()(uint8 row,uint8 col) const
{
    return matrix[index(row,col)];
}


void Mat4::reset()
{
    float identity[16] = 
    {
        1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
        0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,
        0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,
        0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
    };

    std::copy(identity,identity+16,this->matrix);
}


void Mat4::operator=(const Mat4 &other)
{
    for(uint8 row=0 ; row<4 ; row++)
    {
        for(uint8 col=0 ; col<4 ; col++)
        {
            matrix[index(row,col)] = other(row,col);
        }
    }
}


inline const float* const Mat4::valuePtr()
{
    return matrix;
}

}
```

But when I do this..

```
SLMath::Mat4 matrix;
const float *const value = matrix.valuePtr();
```

in main functions It is giving me a linking error...

```
Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float const *    __thiscall SLMath::Mat4::valuePtr(void)" (?valuePtr@Mat4@SLMath@@QAEQBMXZ) referenced in function _main
```

and When I removed inline keyword from the function valuePtr() ..Its working fine.
Please help me...
One more thing is not clear here is that if the compiler is giving error for the function valuePtr() then It should also give the error for the operator()(uint8,uint8) right,because its declared inline?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that could cause this. I'm guessing your build process doesn't link your executable with the compiled translation unit.

Comment: Thank you for the response.. but when I removed inline keyword from the function valuePtr() its working fine.

Comment: We generally put the inline functions in the header. Not all compilers are smart enough to inline from one .cpp file to another. Or only do that at higher optimization levels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An inline function shall be *defined* in each TU which uses it. This means that you cannot place a *declaration* in header and define function in implementation file.

> **7.1.2/4**
>   An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but what about "inline float operator()(uint8,uint8) ?  I declared it in an header file and defined it in other.cpp file and using it in main function without any error.

Comment: @Ankitsinghkushwah If something compiles, it does not mean that it is correct. As no behaviour is mandated for programs which violate this requirement, you are now in the realm of Undefined Behaviour. One possible result of it is that everything appears to work perfectly.

Comment: Okay then I am going to remove those inline keywords from the functions. Thank you very much and any other suggestion regarding my code?